# Eclipse file associations for search

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, preferences

When using "File Search" in eclipse with resulting Java file results in the search window. Originally clicking one of these results used to bring up the Java editor. However, I installed and uninstalled a javascript plugin and now clicking on a Java file brings up the javascript editor.

Anyone know where these options can be changed or restored?

Comment: Try right click in a search and check `Open With` option.

Answer (score 0):

```
Window --> Preferences --> General --> Editors --> File Associations / Content Types
```

Comment: Thanks but the file associations look fine in preferences and when I double click a .java file in the Project Explorer it brings up the Java editor correctly. This problem only occurs in the Search window. I can only assume that there must be corruption of a settings file for the search module.

Answer (score 0):

So worked out that this has nothing to do with file associations or content types. File search is including results that are both inside and outside the classpath. Due to the parent-child structure of my maven project, I get matches for the parent project for source files that are actually in the child. If I click one of these I get an editor that looks a bit like the Java editor but none of the code completions work (that's why I thought it was a javascript editor).

The solution is to create a working set that only includes the child sources and search within that.